# I am working on ASP.NET Core 8 basically learning and having issue about Razor (.cshtml) pages

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

Visual Studio 2022 version 17.8.3 is showing error in "Activating language client: Razor Language Server":

[Here is the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar77D.png)

I try to clear the cache of Visual Studio, but not that did no solve the problem.

This is my cache location:

```
%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.8.3\WebTools\Languages\LanguageServers\ComponentModelCache.
```

Comment: Which version are you using community or professional or enterprise? You can increase `razorLanguageServer` time out duration by setting `timeoutMs` property within the `.vs` folder, create a file named `settings.json`

Comment: I am using community version